# Testing google cloud endpoints locally

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I been trying to write some code using google cloud endpoints IN app engine and I've also signed up for the trusted tester program but my request is still pending, so as far as I know i can access the endpoints only when they are hosted in the appspot domain so is there any way to consume the endpoints locally so that I can continue development until my request is being considered for cloud endpoints as a trusted tester?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't well documented publicly (all the documentation is shared with trusted testers), but you can test locally with the local development server (in Java in the current SDK, and in Python in the SDK shared with testers).

If you're using Java, you can check out instructions in the [codelab](https://tictactoe-codelab.appspot.com).

Comment: I've already downloaded the example but in the index.html page where they have initialized the google client api they have pointed to the appspot domain `var ROOT = https://tictactoe-java.appspot.com/_ah/api` and I tried to change that to `var ROOT = 'http://localhost:8888/_ah/api';` but that does not work. Please point me to some resource. And just asking when is the cloud endpoint going to be released publicly.

Comment: There are currently some issues with using the JS client locally, which is why the sample points to a production domain. You can test locally with `curl` or by using the generated client libraries.

Comment: Ok Dan, let say I have generated the client libraries but can I use them with the js client or is even that not available right now?

Comment: To use the JS client requires you can point it to a deployed application. You can use the Android client against the local server.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I'm keeping my fingers crossed for the trusted tester program. I just nee that dearly. On a side-note is there any foreseeable date on which this will be available publicly.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't give a release date yet.