# Registration with Endpoints Server...FAILED! (emulator worked, phone doesn't)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Code generated by Android Studio>tools>Google Cloud Tools> Generate App Engine Backend
and Generate Endpoint worked in the Emulator,

Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

however I got this error (image from another person's question)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/230G2.png
when I load the app onto my phone and run.  (I did change the LOCAL_ANDROID_RUN to false)

The error implies that there is some Endpoint server running at `http://10.0.2.2:8080`
which I don't expect because I don't really understand where the Endpoint Service runs.  Does it run locally on the phone or somewhere on the Cloud?

I believe generated App Engine code is shipped up to Google through the Maven appengine:update

What am I missing here, thanks
-a

UPDATE (11:24 AM)

executed:
Android Studio>tools>Google Cloud Tools> Generate Client Libraries
which added to -AppEngine/target/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints etc

This changed what happened on the phone.  There is still a registration error but now says:

2) registration with Endpoints Server...FAILED!
Unable to register your device with your Cloud Endpoints server running at https://.appspot.com/_ah/api

UPDATE (11:44 AM)
executed maven script
appengine:update      to get the AppEngine deployed with the new code from Generate Client Libraries

same error on phone (unable to register your device with your Cloud Endpoints server)

UPDATE (1:39 pm)
got logcat info while running app on the phone, hooked up through USB to computer,
looks like a 404 Not Found error (???)

```
12-27 13:36:51.942      609-703/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Delivering touch to: action: 0x1
12-27 13:36:52.412  19103-19103/sic.example.db7 W/AbstractGoogleClient﹕ Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.
12-27 13:36:52.412  19103-19246/sic.example.db7 E/GCMRegistrar﹕ internal error: retry receiver class not set yet
12-27 13:36:53.253  19103-19246/sic.example.db7 E/sic.example.db7.GCMIntentService﹕ Exception received when attempting to register with server at https://core-phoenix-441.appspot.com/_ah/api/
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
Not Found
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:111)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:38)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:312)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1042)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
        at sic.example.db7.GCMIntentService.onRegistered(GCMIntentService.java:158)
        at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.handleRegistration(GCMBaseIntentService.java:296)
        at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMBaseIntentService.java:197)
        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: Have you set your app id in appengine-web.xml? You need to set that value, and then run Android Studio>tools>Google Cloud Tools> Generate Client Libraries. Then deploy.

Comment: looks like that's automatically created through Cloud Tools>Generate App Engine Background, as I see <application>core-phoenix-441</application> in both occurances of appengine-web.xml in both App-AppEngine/target and src

Any URLs to learn more about setting all this up?  Maybe I missed something...

Comment: By "deploy" I assume you mean Maven Projects>Plugins>appengine:update

Comment: You only need to change the app id in the appengine-web.xml file in the src/ folder. On a build, it is moved over to target. I think that as long as you change this value and then run the "Generate Client Libraries" action, and then deploy (using appengine:update), you'll have the right version of the application deployed to appspot.com. Also note that you'll need to rebuild your APK after generating the client libraries. You shouldn't have to tweak any other URLs.

Comment: UPDATE all the code works now (Jan 4) (registration with Google Cloud Messaging, Registration with Endpoints Server

Answer (score 0):

the emulator can access because it runs locally, your phone doesn't have access to the computer localhost. To do that you can check Codiak answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16097253/1368396